# Excel lookup: check with column A if no match check with column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in 3 columns A , B and C and D column have lookup data. First I need to lookup with Column A if there is no match try with column B if there is no match try with C and place the result in E.

Columns:

```
A                  B           C           D(Lookup)        E(Result)
StoreVisits       3M          Lumber       3M                3M
Safety            Craft       honeywell    samsung           honeywell
SamsungFlexWash   POP         Insulation   honeywell         samusng
KitchenAid        HS          Grills       behr              NA
Behr_Q1           Appliances  SMM                            behr
```

I know how to do the lookup by using VLOOKUP. But not able to get the above result? I tried different options from internet but no luck.

Please help me how to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the NA in Column E? Is it for samsung (indicating that it couldn't be found)?

Comment: Not Available. There is no match.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the IFNA clause to check if VLOOKUP is returning result, if not then VLOOKUP in next column. Here is sample for two columns

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP("Value",A:A,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP("Value",B:B,1,FALSE))
```